# QT. Не работают стили в .qml файле

Tags: c++, qt, qml

```
import QtQuick 2.9
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.4
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2

   Button {
        id: trunclateBtn
        text: qsTr("Перевести")
        style: Rectangle{

        }
    }
```

style подчеркивается красным и выбивает ошибку "Неверное название свойства style(M16)", хотя вроде бы все подключил, в документации так же все делается.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*UPD: Изначальный ответ удалён в виду своей бесполезности.*

Всё дело в Qt Quick Controls. У вас используется версия 2, а в ней свойство компонентов `style` было удалено (в отличие от версии 1). Вот [здесь](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtquickcontrols2-differences.html) описаны различия и приведён пример конкретно для `style`.

Чтобы решить вашу проблему надо:

- либо просто изменить `QtQuick.Controls 2.2` на `QtQuick.Controls 1.2`;
- либо оставить версию 2.2, но использовать свойство `contentItem`.

Вариант для `QtQuick.Controls 2.2`:

```
Button {
    contentItem: Rectangle {
        width: 100
        height: 20
        color: "red"
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Сделал как указано в вашем примере кода, ошибка та же

Comment: Ок, извиняюсь. Пофиксила ответ.

Comment: Действительно, спасибо!

Comment: Прошу еще немного помочь. Я попробовал версию 1.4, но там стандартно оно выглядит все неочень, к тому же недоступны некторые функции, поэтому хотелось бы делать оформление на версии 2.2. Но я толком понять не могу где как это правильно делать, даже если брать ваш пример, то прямоуголник не заполняет кнопку полностю, даже если padding:0 сделать, то все равно вылазит кнопка. Так как же мне все-таки правильно делать дизайн виджетов?

Comment: @VladRoss возможно, `anchors.fill: parent` вам поможет (внутри `Rectangle`)?

Comment: Да, это помогло, но я все-таки на 1.4 останусь, наверное так будет проще, все равно дизайн и так переделывать буду

Comment: @VladRoss удачи! Как вариант, если вы хотите какие-то свои особенные кнопки, вы можете вместо `Button` сделать `Rectangle` с `MouseArea` внутри. И обрабатывать события `onClicked`. По факту это получится тот же `Button`.

Comment: Neilana, у меня еще один вопрос, если я Вам еще не надоел, касательно интерфейса. Я наткнулся на данную статью https://evileg.com/ru/post/182/ и хотел бы спросить, не является ли данное решение костыльным, возможно есть более правильные варианты? В приницпе оно вроде работает нормльно, но главная проблема, что в графическом редакторе из-за того что я подставляю функцию вместо значения ломаются положения виджетов, и к тому же приходится везде поставлять эту функцию, что тоже не очень удобно. Возможно есть варианты поправильнее?

Comment: @VladRoss буду откровенна, с масштабируемым интерфейсом под Андроид дела пока не имела, поэтому не знаю какие там есть подводные камни. Всё, что могу вам сказать: 1) в принципе подставлять функцию вместо значения - нормальная практика, ничего костыльного в этом нет; 2) evileg, автор данного ресурса, более опытный разработчик чем я и его уроки, наверно чуть ли не единственные по QML, которые можно найти на русском языке, поэтому ему я склонна верить больше чем себе :)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо еще раз, буду думать как привести это к виду в редакторе, если это возможно.